# Time complexity algorithm

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity

I have an algorithm that does O(n) work, gets rid of a
constant fraction 1/k of the input (k > 2), and calls itself recursively
on what remains. The algorithm can be described by
T(n) = T( ( (k-1)/k)*n)+O(n). How do I calculate the closed form for T(n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can expand it directly:
T(n) = T(((k - 1)/k)^2 * n) + O(((k - 1)/k) * n) + O(n) and so on

Note that n * ((k-1)/k) is n / (k / (k - 1)) which implies a denominator > 1.

Hence it is a geometric series that converges to a sum n / ( 1 - (k - 1)/k) = n * k.

Hence T(n) = O(n*k) which is O(n) if k is constant.

Comment: isn't O(n*k) the same as O(n) in terms of algorithmic complexity? (really only know basics about this stuff, but i'd be interested)

Comment: If the input has something to do with k then it isn't. For example there may be k colors and n boxes and a coloring algorithm's complexity may depend on both.

Comment: If the denominator is > 1 the sum has an upper bound. Else it will be unbounded, I.e. infinite.

Comment: Ah okay, so for every constant k which is defined ahead and may not change depending on input, O(n) and O(k*n) would be the same, but for every k which depends on the input or could change, it won't be the same? But then k isn't a constant anymore or? Confused.

Comment: Yes, you're right. The problem mentions k as a constant. Edited.

Comment: Thx, got it now! (upvoted of course, now that I also understand it ;) )

Answer (score 1):

You might want to read about the Master Theorem, which is a convenient way to analyze this kind of problems: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem

Your algorithm would fall into case 3, where the recursive work is negligible compared to the work outside.